# Percentage wildcard does not return on perfect match

Tags: mysql, doctrine, typo3, typo3-8.x

I build a query using the TYPO3 8.7 query builder trying to allocate zipcodes in a column of unique 5 digit zipcodes.

```
->where($queryBuilder
        ->expr()
        ->like('zip_column', $queryBuilder->createNamedParameter($zip . '%', \PDO::PARAM_STR)))
```

and so on.

I get a response on 4 digits, but not when enteringer 5 digits perfect match zip-code.

There should be a response on a perfect match with e.g. `01234%` when there is an entry 01234, but it won't work.

Comment: What is the actual SQL query which has been created? Can you add the debug info here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't now know what the problem was. It suddenly just worked out well. Some kind of caching or problem in my local environment must have created this weird behaviour.

Thanks for your answers.